# How do I calculate the gravitation of a micro black hole (millions of tonnes range) at a given distance?

Tags: black-holes

Let's say there was a method of creating an artificial black hole in the millions or billions of tonnes range.  And let's say there was some device that could contain it, for instance a meter-diameter sphere.  My question is how much gravitation would be felt on the surface of that sphere, at ten meters away, a hundred meters away, etc.?

Comment: $F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$

Answer (score 3):

You can use Newton's equations to calculate the potential and the force. It's a weak enough force for the example numbers you've given that Newton's equations,  is close enough to the exact value, and you don't need General Relativity.

For comparison the earth at about $10^{24}$ kg has a Schwarzschild radius of .35 inches. So at distances of say 1000 times that, or 30 ft or 10 meters, it is weak enough that you can use Newton's equations. In fact it's good enough even further in. If you are close enough, or have extremely accurate and precise instrumentation, you can see some differences. In that case you can use the Schwarzschild solution to get the answer. If you are within say 10 times that Schwarzschild radius, you will experience obvious relativistic effects like time dilation, and tidal forces on your body. Of course anywhere close to something that massive you will feel much much heavier (if you were standing on some surface that held you up, or equivalently it would be the rocket forces needed to keep you at a fixed distance from the black hole).

See some of the sizes of the Schwarzschild radius at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius. It depends on the mass of the object linearly. The recent black holes that have been detected with LIGO have masses about 30-60 times that of the Sun, with Schwarzschild radius in the 100 Kms range.

The Schwarzscild solution for when you are closer to the black holes are at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric. It is valid if the black hole is non-rotating. If it rotates strong enough it can also drag you around it, and the solution is called the Kerr solution, and you can google it or find it in Wikipedia.

Keep in mind that for those general relativistic solutions weight is not the most relevant number (as I have indicated above); you won't feel your own weight unless a rocket or something similar is holding you up. But you will feel the tidal forces, and fall into the black hole, and get stretched and thinned out infinitely as you get closer to its singularity (for spherical black holes, roughly the center). Of course you won't be alive either. But if you use the General Relativistic solution, you can calculate all of that (before you die maybe).